# GAE app not behaving same as local server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urllib2, mechanize, ntlm

I'm using virtualenv and copied the contents of the site-packages folder inside my projects libs folder.

This is my code;

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "libs"))
import webapp2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from ntlm import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler
import urllib2
import mechanize

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        usr = self.request.get('usr')
        password = self.request.get('pw')

        url = "http://www.dogus.edu.tr/dusor/"
        user = 'ata.dogus.edu.tr\\' + usr

        passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
        passman.add_password(None, url, user, password)
        auth_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(passman)

        br = mechanize.Browser()

        br.handlers = [handler for handler in br.handlers if not isinstance(handler, (mechanize._http.HTTPRobotRulesProcessor))]
        br.add_handler(auth_NTLM)

        try:
            br.addheaders = [('Cookie', br.open(url).info().dict['set-cookie'].split(';')[0])]
        except KeyError:
            self.response.write('Hatali Sifre veya kullanici adi.')
            return

        response = br.open(url+'FrmMain.aspx')

        response = br.open(url+'FrmNot.aspx')
        rows = [row.contents for row in BeautifulSoup(response.read()).find_all('table', id='dgnot')[-1].find_all('tr', align='left')]

        dersler = [[i.string.strip() for i in row] for row in rows]

        resp = '\n<br><br>\n'.join([' - '.join(ders) for ders in dersler])
        print resp

        self.response.write(resp)
        self.response.write('AAAAA')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)

def main():
    from paste import httpserver
    httpserver.serve(app, host='127.0.0.1', port='8080')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When running this script from virtualenv's python `http://127.0.0.1:8080/?usr=1331025&pw=123456` returns the expected result. However, after uploading my app to GAE i get an error like this;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~dusorbb/1.375812550365780990/main.py", line 27, in get
    br.addheaders = [('Cookie', br.open(url).info().dict['set-cookie'].split(';')[0])]
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~dusorbb/1.375812550365780990/libs/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~dusorbb/1.375812550365780990/libs/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 230, in _mech_open
    response = UserAgentBase.open(self, request, data)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~dusorbb/1.375812550365780990/libs/mechanize/_opener.py", line 204, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~dusorbb/1.375812550365780990/libs/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 457, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~dusorbb/1.375812550365780990/libs/mechanize/_opener.py", line 221, in error
    result = apply(self._call_chain, args)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~dusorbb/1.375812550365780990/libs/mechanize/_urllib2_fork.py", line 332, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~dusorbb/1.375812550365780990/libs/ntlm/HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.py", line 99, in http_error_401
    return self.http_error_authentication_required('www-authenticate', req, fp, headers)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~dusorbb/1.375812550365780990/libs/ntlm/HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.py", line 35, in http_error_authentication_required
    return self.retry_using_http_NTLM_auth(req, auth_header_field, None, headers)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~dusorbb/1.375812550365780990/libs/ntlm/HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.py", line 63, in retry_using_http_NTLM_auth
    r._safe_read(int(r.getheader('content-length')))
AttributeError: HTTPResponse instance has no attribute '_safe_read'
```

Also i tried copying the libraries to the root of my app's folder and commenting out the line `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "libs"))` and got the same error. What may be the problem here?

Comment: I doubt the problem is to do with how your modify sys.path.  you are using mechanise and ntlm.  Unless you have billing enabled and are using sockets, you will be using URLFetch under the hood, and the response object probably doesn't have a `_safe_read` method.

Comment: @TimHoffman This is for a school project. Is there another free alternative that will host my application properly?